# insertRowsAtIndexPaths question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to add a row to my tableview cell asynchronously and I did some research it seems that the way to do it is by using:

insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

now what is the indexPaths here? I have an array of Sports objects (which is the model) and what I did is to add a new Sports entry to it. I don't want to reload the whole data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index path would specify as a row the row you inserted in your model. So if it was the last row, you'd use that index into your model as the row value in an `NSIndexPath` object.

You want to enclose your call to insertRowsAtIndexPath between calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates, too.

Comment: so if my model is an array then this is the same as the number of elements in the array - 1?

Comment: Yup. If you have sections, then you have to deal with that, or just specify 0 for the section (in the index path).